# Use google spreadsheet only for it's interface, without google account or connection

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-apps, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to use google spread sheets's nice interface, without a connection with any google account.

The scenario is, that I will add spreadsheets.dll to my project, then I will create & use the awesome excel interface, and save the documents to my own database or storage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To create a spreadsheet and to other tasks in Google Sheets a Google account is required but once a spreadsheet is created the owner and editors could share it publicly.

Comment: Thanks. I want it without google account, without google support. Just the interface, and store the data somewhere else.